# For Loop not looping and detecting Char Array [Pointers and Char Arrays]

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Basically, the code is asking for a user input. I type in the word hotkdog and I would like to use the function FindIndexOfCharacter 'k', which is 3. However, the function is always returning -1, so I guess my loop isn't being ++i for some reason??

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

void ReadString(char * c, int maxLength);
int FindIndexOfCharacter(char * c, char testVal);

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 10;
    char ca[SIZE];
    char * cpointer = ca;

    ReadString(cpointer, 10);
    std::cout << FindIndexOfCharacter(cpointer, 'k');
    system("pause");
}

void ReadString(char * c, int Length)
{
    std::cout << "Enter a string " << Length << " characters." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> c;
}

int FindIndexOfCharacter(char * c, char Val)
{
    int sizeOfArray2 = std::strlen(c);
    std::cout << sizeOfArray2 << std::endl; // this confirms array size

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray2; ++i)
    {
        if (c[i] == Val)
            return i;
        else
            return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: of course it doesn't `++i`, you are `return`ing on the first iteration of the loop

Comment: You have a possible buffer overrun issue:  `std::cin >> c`.  Type 12 characters and find out.

Comment: I highly recommend replacing your loop in `FindIndexOfChar` with `strchr`.  Since the `strchr` returns a pointer to an array, you can subtract the start of the array from the result of `strchr` to get the index.  Remember to validate the result from `strchr` before calculating the index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray2; ++i)
{
    if (c[i] == Val)
        return i;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

You're only checking the first character. If it doesn't match, you return `-1` right away.

Instead you need to proceed to the next character.

Perhaps try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeOfArray2; ++i)
{
    if (c[i] == Val)
        return i;
}

return -1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change your function:

```
char * p_found = strchr(c, Val);
if (p_found != nullptr)
{
  return p_found - c;
}
return -1;
```